# How to capture the Parameters being sent to a particular Stored Procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

In SQL Server 2008R2, do we have a query which can find the parameters being passed to a particular stored procedure?

Comment: Can you not run a trace in profiler? Also, not that it makes much difference, but your tags say you're using 2008R2, but your title says you're using 2008 - could you please clarify?

Comment: Yup its SqlServer 2008 R2. Do we have a magic table like INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES which does the job ?

Comment: I'm afraid not - best I can see is `sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats`, but that only shows last execution time. I don't think you can capture them, unless you happen to be running a Profiler trace at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. Query will be

```
select PARAMETER_NAME,DATA_TYPE from information_schema.parameters where specific_name = 'StoredProcName'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sql server doesn't keep the history of query execution. So there is not anyway to know parameters being passed to a particular stored procedure. If you want you can write a script in the procdure itself and keep all values in some tables. Or you can save query profile data in the trace file or in some table etc.